# macOS Mojave throws error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno' when running ruby-build

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I'm trying to upgrade ruby on my system to `2.6.1` using `rbenv`, but I keep getting an error that I can't figure out.

I upgraded my system to the latest macOS version (10.14.3) and made sure Xcode 10.1 and the CLI tools were installed as well. I removed `ruby-build` and `rbenv` via `homebrew` and reinstalled with the latest versions. I'm still getting the error.

Here is the portion of the log that shows the error:

```
compiling enumerator.c
cont.c:897:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        errno = 0;
        ^
cont.c:900:80: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
            rb_raise(rb_eFiberError, "can't alloc machine stack to fiber: %s", ERRNOMSG);
                                                                               ^
cont.c:862:27: note: expanded from macro 'ERRNOMSG'
#define ERRNOMSG strerror(errno)
                          ^
cont.c:906:68: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
            rb_raise(rb_eFiberError, "can't set a guard page: %s", ERRNOMSG);
                                                                   ^
cont.c:862:27: note: expanded from macro 'ERRNOMSG'
#define ERRNOMSG strerror(errno)
                          ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [cont.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
dir.c:562:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        int e = errno;
                ^
dir.c:567:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EIO'
        else if (e == EIO) {
                      ^
dir.c:788:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
    errno = 0;
    ^
dir.c:793:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        int e = errno;
                ^
dir.c:1363:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENOENT'
    return e == ENOENT || e == ENOTDIR;
                ^
dir.c:1363:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ENOTDIR'
    return e == ENOENT || e == ENOTDIR;
                               ^
dir.c:1401:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
    if (ret < 0 && !to_be_ignored(errno))
                                  ^
dir.c:1416:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
    if (ret < 0 && !to_be_ignored(errno))
                                  ^
dir.c:1463:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        int e = errno;
                ^
dir.c:1516:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        int e = errno;
                ^
dir.c:1804:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        if (!to_be_ignored(errno))
                           ^
dir.c:1993:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EACCES'
    if (error == EACCES) {
                 ^
dir.c:2221:42: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
            if ((magical < 2) && !recursive && (errno == EACCES)) {
                                                ^
dir.c:2221:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EACCES'
            if ((magical < 2) && !recursive && (errno == EACCES)) {
                                                         ^
dir.c:3292:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
        int e = errno;
                ^
15 errors generated.
make: *** [dir.o] Error 1
```

Has anyone else seen this error? I checked the `ruby-build` issues on Github. It looks like someone else has a [similar issue](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1281), but not this specific one.

Comment: `errno` is a standard constant defined in `sys/errno.h`, practically every syscall uses it. The fact that it can't be found means something is wrong with the C compiler that rbenv is using. Is there a way for you to see what compiler commands it is running?

Comment: It's running 
`Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)`
`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0`
`Thread model: posix`
and compiling the ruby source. When it gets to `compiling enumerator.c`, that's where it's throwing the error.

Other than that, I'm not sure how to go deeper into the compilation.

Comment: It looks like `rbenv` is picking up the wrong headers.  If you run `brew doctor` does it list any unbrewed header files?